# why does a syntax error in a while loop interrupt the script (but does not outside the while loop)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Consider these three bash scripts:

- script without a syntax error - executes without errors, as expected, loops "this is the end: -1":

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do
    x=1 # or, read the variable from some external source
    y=2 # or, read the variable from some external source
    z=$(( $x - $y ))
    echo "this is the result: $z"
    sleep 1
done
```

Execution - infinite loop, until we interrupt:

```
$ bash test.sh
this is the result: -1
this is the result: -1
this is the result: -1
^C
```

- script which results in a syntax error (note the missing x and y variables, which are then needed for a calculation):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do
    x= # or, read the variable from some external source
    y= # or, read the variable from some external source
    z=$(( $x - $y ))
    echo "this is the result: $z"
    sleep 1
done
```

Execution - bash interrupts script execution when there is a syntax error:

```
$ bash test.sh
test.sh: line 6: -  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-  ")
```

- script without a while loop - script execution is not interrupted:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=
y=
z=$(( $x - $y ))
echo "this is the result: $z"
```

Execution - bash notices a syntax error in calculation, but does NOT interrupt script execution:

```
$ bash test.sh
test.sh: line 5: -  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-  ")
this is the result:
```

Why does bash behave differently upon getting a syntax error, depending on whether it's in a while loop or not?
EDIT: I'm aware input variables could/should be verified, and there are various ways to do it. I was more interested why it behaves differently, depending on whether we're in a while loop or not.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is not whether it's in a loop or not; the difference is that the variable is empty.

```sh
$ bash  # start a fresh instance
bash$ x=''
bash$ y=''
bash$ $(( $x - $y ))
bash: -  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

As noted by @oguzismail in a comment, the syntax error actually doesn't cause the whole script to exit; it causes the *compound command* (i.e. the `while` loop) to abort. You can demonstrate this by adding `echo "still here"` after the `done` line.

If you want to prevent this from happening when you receive `x` and `y` from an external source, maybe check if they contain any non-numeric characters?

```sh
case ${x#-}${y#-} in
  *[!0-9]*)
    echo "$0: error; $x and $y need to be strictly numeric" >&2
    exit 74;;
esac
```

Notice the hack to trim off a single minus sign if present by way of a [parameter expansion.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

As @LéaGris points out, in Bash, you could also simply say `declare -i x y` to have the shell constrain the possible values for `x` and `y` to integers; then they will be coerced to `0` if they receive invalid values.

Comment: The third snippet (without a while loop) also had empty variables, but was not interrupted. Unless I'm looking in a wrong place?

Comment: This looks like a bug. The reference manual [specifies this behavior in POSIX mode](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode), but your script is not executing in POSIX mode. *("28. Non-interactive shells exit if a syntax error in an arithmetic expansion results in an invalid expression.")*

Comment: No, not a bug actually. Shell errors terminate all compound commands in Bash. If you put, let's say `echo x`, after the while loop, you'd see that the script is not interrupted.

Comment: @tripleee if using bash, don't miss the alternative to secure integer numbers with an `i` flag on variables: `declare -i x y`